# Переопределение методов классов в странной ситуации

Tags: c#, ооп

Я видел как один человек после наследования функциональности одного класса другим переопределял методы, не добавляя никакой логики в них.
То есть приведу пример:

```
class A{
...
public virtual void Calc() // здесь есть уже логика
}

class B: A{
 public void override Calc(){
   base.Calc(); 
 }
}
```

То есть казалось бы по умолчанию и так уже есть этот функционал в виде метода Calc() и можно было бы не переопределять его, чтобы использовать для своих задач, но здесь как то странно...Имеет ли смысл так переопределять методы в какой-то ситуации или нет?

Comment: у тебя функция Calc не может быть с `override`, потому что это не виртуальная и не абстрактная функция

Comment: Возможно, тому человеку платят за количество строк кода. Вот он и имитирует бурную деятельность.

Comment: Переопределять без добавления кода - бессмысленное занятие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Представьте, у вас есть 1 класс, у которого есть некоторая логика по нанесению урона. У данного класса идеально всё протестировано и всё прекрасно работает. От него наследуются множество классов: ёжики, феи, ведьмы и прочее.

```
internal abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int HP { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void Damage(int damage)
    {
        HP -= damage;
    }
}
```

Но тут вы захотели добавить змею себе в игру, по которой проходит двойной урон, в случае, если после основного урона у неё остаётся меньше 50 здоровья. Очевидно, что вы не будете переписывать логику базового класса, а просто добавите переопределение основного.

```
internal class Snake : BaseEntity
{
    public override void Damage(int damage)
    {
        base.Damage(damage);
        if (HP < 50)
            HP -= damage * 2;
    }
}
```

А теперь представьте, что вы добавили обычного персонажа Player, по которому не проходит какой-то дополнительный урон и т.д, но у него так же есть какие-то свои характеристики (показатели брони и т.д.)

```
internal class Player : BaseEntity
{ 
    public int Armor { get; private set; }
}
```

В таком случае, переопределять метод Damage не имеет смысла, т.к. это будет не больше, чем бесполезное увеличение количества строк кода. Необходимо лишь вызвать метод Damage у базового класса (BaseEntity)

```
BaseEntity player = new Player();
player.Damage(20);
```

Comment: у тебя в классе змеи хп отнимается два раза, первый раз при вызове `base.Damage(damage)`, второй если срабатывает условие. Но по идее должно отниматься в зависимости от условия либо просто damage, либо damage*2, не?

Comment: Это просто пример, притянутый за уши. Не принимайте это настолько близко. Как пример с котиками и собачками из ютуба

Comment: @Frehzy Пример в любом случае должен быть корректным. Если описание не соответствует коду, то нужно исправить либо код, либо описание. Чтобы не было лишних вопросов.

Comment: @CrazyElf А чем описание не соответствует коду? "Но тут вы захотели добавить змею себе в игру, по которой проходит двойной урон, в случае, если ПОСЛЕ основного урона у неё остаётся меньше 50 здоровья.". Логическая цепочка следующая: Наносим урон змее. Если у неё меньше 50 здоровья, то отнимаем ещё столько же хп, умноженное на два, потому что змея почти умерла. Не вижу проблем с описанием и соответствием код/описание кода. Как по мне, пример является корректным. Конечно, можно было написать банальное с зоопарком, где животные разные звуки издают, но это уже слишком приелось

Comment: А, ну ладно, если дополнительный двойной урон после, то описание корректное. Но если у двоих уже возникло неправильное понимание, то что-то всё же в описании не совсем понятно. Но так то ладно, теперь понятно.